# Получить данные PHP

Tags: php

Как получить href?

```
$results = file_get_contents("php://input"); (вебхук)
file_put_contents('customerorder.txt', $results);
```

Приходит:

```
{"events":[{"meta":{"type":"customerorder","href":"https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/customerorder/d336916f-f4f1-11e7-7a6c-d2a90046d3ca"},"action":"UPDATE"}]}
```

Пробовал разные варианты, например, чтобы хоть что-то получить:

```
$results = file_get_contents('customerorder.txt');
echo $results;
```

А там пустота, причем после выполнения кода в браузере.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще сделать ассоциативный массив то есть `json_decode($result, true);` Таким образом не потребуется обращаться к неизвестному объекту типа     `stdClass` с непонятной сигнатурой. Хотя конечно лучше всего было бы написать абстрактный адаптер к этим данным.

UPD: Добавлю почему лучше использовать ассоциативный массив в таких случаях. Имея массив, мы можем проще написать валидацию данных, то есть проверку на консистентность ответа. В случае с stdClass проверка ответа на консистентность будет сложнее.

Comment: Хмм... странно, это ответ ? Тут нет неизвестного объекта (+ с непонятной сигнатурой), все данные идут по API moysklad.ru, где все данные известны и описаны в документации

Comment: @Arsen работать с `stdClass` в PHP не очень удобно - отсутствуют стандартные методы. Плюс у новичков понимание `SPL` довольно низко, поэтому и предлагаю перегонять данные в массивы, так как они понятнее начинающим.

Comment: @Arsen и да, давайте будем реалистами, если поменяется сигнатура объекта ответа используя массив, нам будет проще написать проверки, чем используя `stdClass` , так как для исследования классов нужно создавать объекты рефлексии.

Answer (score 3):

Это к вам прилетает объект в формате `Json`, для получения доступа к элементам объекта в первую очередь вам надо сделать `json_decode` и только после получите доступ к `href`:  `object->events[0]->meta->href`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делаю так: '$results = file_get_contents("php://input");
$results = json_decode($results);
file_put_contents('customerorder.txt', $results);' и данные теряются со 2 строкой.

Comment: Тоже изначально применял json_decode.

Comment: @TimurMusharapov  думаю у вас проблема на этапе php://input, надо с самого начала по шагам проверить всё.

Comment: Тимур, вы десериализовали данные, а перед записью в файл нужно их обратно сериализовать

Comment: $results = file_get_contents("php://input");
$results = json_decode($results, true);
file_put_contents('customerorder.txt', $results->events[0]->meta->href); Также пустота.