# Как вырезать текст php

Tags: php, массивы, веб-программирование, переменные

Есть вот такой текст:

```
{"mid":168260,"date":1519379012,"out":0,"uid":238539918,"read_state":1,"title":"","body":"Привет"},{"mid":168252,"date":1519228509,"out":0,"uid":238539918,"read_state":1,"title":"","body":"hello"},{"mid":168251,"date":1519228477,"out":0,"uid":238539918,"read_state":1,"title":"","body":"ребусы"},{"mid":168250,"date":1519228266,"out":0,"uid":238539918,"read_state":1,"title":"","body":"машина едет по грязи,песку"},
{"mid":168249,"date":1519228250,"out":0,"uid":238539918,"read_state":1,"title":"","body":"PHP — скриптовый язык общего назначения, интенсивно применяемый для разработки веб-приложений."}.
```

Нужно вырезать из него  данные c body.

```
body[0]=Привет; 
body[1]=hello;
body[2]=ребусы;
body[3]= машина едет по грязи,песку;
body[4]= PHP — скриптовый язык общего назначения, интенсивно применяемый для разработки веб-приложений.;
```

Comment: на будущее - это __строка формата json__, примеров извлечения массивов из json в инете миллион.

Comment: Это уже много раз обсуждалось, например тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/785870/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-php/785877#785877

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$json_string = '{"mid":168260,"date":1519379012,"out":0,"uid":238539918,"read_state":1,"title":"","body":"Привет"}';

$obj = json_decode($json_string);
echo $obj->{'body'};
```